# undefined method 'user' for nil:nilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

According to the One Month Rails course in the session: `Pins Users and Associations` i have to do the following after running `rails console`:

```
Pin.connection #This establishes a connection to the database (And spits out a LOT of unnecessary data)

Pin.inspect #shows all of the parameters for a Pin 
CONTROL + D #closes the Console 

pin = Pin.first #make sure Pin.first is UPPERCASE
pin.user
```

But when i write `pin.user` i get an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass`

I have added `belongs_to :user` and `has_many :pins`

I dont understand why i am getting that error.

My github is https://github.com/frankzk/pinteresting

Comment: `pin.user` should be `Pin.user(caps P)` i guess.

Comment: do you have any pins in the database? it's saying `pin = Pin.first` returns nil

Comment: if what you did was `pin = Pin.first`, then there is no `pin` in your database, you need to create a `Pin`

Comment: `pin = Pin.first` returns `nil` and you are trying to get user instance from `nil` object. So that you are getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @bjhaid how do i create a a Pin?

Comment: @user3626947 I just checked your repo on github there is no relationship between `Pin` and `User`, you might either need to go through the tutorial on Association all over again if you missed anything or...

Comment: @bjhaid please, have a look again. I have updated my github

Comment: `pins` table is empty

Comment: @user3626947 just `new_pin = Pin.create`

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, the error is created because the original object (in your case `@pin`) is not populated with any data (hence it being `nil`).

--

**Error**

A lot of beginners get confused about this error, but it's quite simple:

```
@pin.user
```

^ this calls `.user` on the `@pin` object. The `user` method is created from your rails associations (`belongs_to :user`), and is meant to provide you with the associative data.

The problem you have is you're calling `.user` on an object which is not populated (it's part of the `'nil'` class), consequently preventing the `.user` method from actually running.

--

**Fix**

To fix this, you should do this:

```
#app/controllers/pins_controller.rb
Class PinsController < ActieRecord::Base
    def show
        @pin = Pin.find params[:id] #-> or Pin.first
    end
end

#app/views/pins/show.html.erb
<%= @pin.user %>
```

If you get errors after this, it generally means you either have data inconsistency (no data in your db), or some other part of your system is incoherent.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure pins table has the column name user_id. Or check whether the record in the database exists for the first Pin or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me, all of your code is correct and Mattan has just put a little piece of code in the wrong place.

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Make sure that `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]` is at the **top** of the list there.

EDIT:  Actually I see you are on an earlier part of the lesson; I'll leave this answer up though because I was directed to this question when trying to figure out the authorization part.